# Projection issue - layers misaligned despite same coordinate system (British National Grid) in ArcMap

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap

I'm having projection issues with a shape file containing habitat information not lining up with my other layers. This is particularly evident when comparing the shape file to the aerial imagery layer I'm using, which is downloaded from Digimap (see image of water bodies). All layers are using the same coordinate system, British National Grid. I have tried setting the coordinate system then importing the files in different orders with the same result. I'm working in ArcMap 10.7 but I've also opened the files in QGIS with the same issue. I'm a GIS beginner, is there anything else I should check or do to resolve this issue?

[image: Habitat layer and aerial imagery layer]

Comment: This appears to be a datum transformation issue, which is a rather esoteric problem for a beginner. Basically, every projection has geographic coordinate system (GCS) which defines the mathematical surface of  the *oblate spheroid* of the Earth. Different GCS may have a different "center" point relative to each other; this is called a *datum*. When projecting between different coordinate systems based on different datums, care must be taken to include the math to shift the centers. This probably did not happen. It may not be your fault, and it may be impossible to correct. Sorry.

Comment: You might get something usable by adjusting a copy of your shapefile with the spatial adjustment toolbar.  I suggest spending some time reading on its use.  You will want a nice distribution of control points across you area of interest and then you could see how the different adjustment methods work.  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/about-spatial-adjustment.htm